# Matching over a Group or Partition in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have dataframe like this:

```
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| company|          id|ann_rtn_dt|share_class_nb|shrhldr_seq_nb|shrhldr_first_nm|shrhldr_mid_nm|shrhldr_sur_nm|
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_1_1|2022-11-28|             1|             1|            NIEL|        ANDREW|        HOPSON|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NICOLE|        CLAIRE|          MORE|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_1_2|2022-11-28|             1|             2|               N|             C|          MORE|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_2_1|2022-11-28|             2|             1|            NEIL|        ANDREW|        HOPSON|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NICOLE|        CLAIRE|          MORE|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_1_1|2022-11-28|             1|             1|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NIMIKE|              |        LOPSON|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_1_2|2022-11-28|             1|             2|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_2_1|2022-11-28|             2|             1|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON|
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The whole dataframe can be grouped 2 distinct `company` column i.e. `SYNTE01` and `SYNTHE02`.

My use case is to do matching inside the `company`.

`STATUS_1` is set to `min` of `id`, when there is full match of `shrhldr_first_nm`, `shrhldr_mid_nm` and  `shrhldr_sur_nm` in the grouop.

`STATUS_2` is set to `min` of `id`, when there is match of first byte of `shrhldr_first_nm` and `shrhldr_mid_nm` in the group. And `shrhldr_sur_nm` matches exactly.

For eg. in `COMPANY` `SYNTHE01`, NIEL ANDREW HOPSON in row1 matches with NIEL ANDREW HOPSON in row4. The column `STATUS_1` is set to `min` of `id` column for both.

For eg. in `COMPANY` `SYNTHE01`, the first byte of NICOLE CLAIRE MORE in row2 matches with N C More in row3. The column `STATUS_2` is set to `min` of `id` column for both.

My output dataframe would look like below:

```
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| company|          id|ann_rtn_dt|share_class_nb|shrhldr_seq_nb|shrhldr_first_nm|shrhldr_mid_nm|shrhldr_sur_nm|     STATUS_1|     STATUS_2|
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_1_1|2022-11-28|             1|             1|            NIEL|        ANDREW|        HOPSON| SYNTHE01_1_1|             |
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NICOLE|        CLAIRE|          MORE| SYNTHE01_3_1| SYNTHE01_1_2|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_1_2|2022-11-28|             1|             2|               N|             C|          MORE|             | SYNTHE01_1_2|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_2_1|2022-11-28|             2|             1|            NEIL|        ANDREW|        HOPSON| SYNTHE01_1_1|             |
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_3_2|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NICOLE|        CLAIRE|          MORE| SYNTHE01_3_1| SYNTHE01_1_2|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_1_1|2022-11-28|             1|             1|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON| SYNTHE02_1_1|             |
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NIMIKE|              |        LOPSON|             |             |
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_1_2|2022-11-28|             1|             2|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON| SYNTHE02_1_1|             |
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_2_1|2022-11-28|             2|             1|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON| SYNTHE02_1_1|             |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Please suggest any possible approach. Thank you.